# Finite order entire function bounded on the boundary of an half-strip

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f$ is an entire function of finite order. Prove that if $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$ on the boundary of the horizontal half-strip $$S = \{ z\in \Bbb C \mid \text{Re}(z)\geq 0, |\text{Im}(z)|\leq 1 \}$$ then $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z \in S$.

I just started reading about the order of an entire function and I'm unsure how to proceed. Can you give me some hints about how to start solving it? (I'm not looking for a complete solution, just some hints)

My Idea is to use some kind of Maximum modulus results, but there are clearly some tweaks to do, since the region is not bounded. Moreover I don't know how to use the assumption about the finiteness of the finite order of $f$

Comment: This is a Phragmen-Lindelof theorem, which, indeed, uses the finite-order assumption, and has some other clever mechanisms. You oughtn't think that you could easily hit upon the proof yourself.

Comment: That was a past exam question, and I'm not sure whether they covered this topic or not :(

Comment: @paulgarrett I've looked the statement of Phragmén–Lindelöf principle on wiki. I'm unsure how to use it since my strip has an angle of $\pi$, hence the order of my function must be strictly less than $1$ in order to use the result. Am I doing something wrong?